# How to create a rest api in app maker?

Tags: rest, google-app-maker

Is there a way to create a REST API in a server side script in app maker?

I need to call a server side function from an iOS app passing some parameters and have a response without having to go to a page in the app.

I know that for regular google apps script it’s possible trough the Execution API but I don’t know how to do it inside app maker.

Thanks.

Comment: App Maker is almost ordinary App Script app... in theory it should work in the same way. Did you try Execution API? Where did you fail?

Comment: Cant figure out how to set it up. All the documentation for the execution api assumes that you have a script file that you can deploy, but most steps dont apply to app maker since you cant configure anything about the scripts. And the settings for the app are very different for the ones available to an individual script outside of app maker.

Comment: well... you can try impement your own api via doGet/doPost https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: I have filed a feature request for an API of some sort at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71673285.  If you want this, please star it.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

You cannot use App Maker via Execution API at this time

---

I tried to use App Script Execution API with App Maker and here are my findings:

- You can enable Execution API for App Maker app deployment in Google Cloud Console, just go to Settings -> Deployments -> Select deployment -> View Logs (these steps will navigate you to associated Cloud Project), then follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name) to enable API itself and create credentials:
  [image]
- Next goes deal breaker for combining App Maker and Execution API... To use App Script app as API you need to deploy it as 'API executable', but App Maker publishes its deployments as 'web app'... I'm not sure, if one can have App Script app simultaneously published both as 'web app' and 'API executable', but even if it is possible App Maker doesn't allow you do it at this time.