# Google App maker API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have a requirement to pull and post data to another application. App maker provides URL fetch option to get data from public API's.

I want to access data from a application in my intranet server does app maker provides any option to connect to the outside server.

URL Fetch option is used to consume data, if I need to pass some data is there any option available to do this in app script

Comment: Try the [External API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external). This documentation will guide you to work in different types of APIs in your script. You can connect to the public APIs using [**`UrlFetch`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) which directly requests APIs. There is an example that was taken from [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) that was also supplied in the documentation.

Comment: I want to pass credential in the URl fetch method, is that possible in that method

Answer (score 1):

> I have a requirement to pull and post data to another application

If you don't have strong requirements on a way how to pull/post the data you can consider sharing data via database:

**Option one: shared database**

You can connect App Maker and your other apps to the same Google Cloud SQL database

**Option two: direct database connection**

Let's say, you have App Maker app connected to Google Cloud SQL database and some internal apps connected to your internal databases. From App Maker side you can connect to your internal databases using [JDBC service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/) and you can whitelist your internal apps to connect to your Cloud SQL instance that App Maker app is connected to.

**Option three: API way**

- At this time App Maker app cannot serve as API endpoint([How to create a rest api in app maker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909358/))
- But in theory it should work fine with third party services([External API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external))