# App Maker Document approval template : How can I Add Default Approvers

Tags: google-app-maker

I use document approval template, and I want to define default approver and stages.

I have tried to change the custom value associates to the `userpicker` widget in `EditRequest` Page to define a default Approver by changing the location from `onValueChange` to `onAttach`. I set default value for mail's approvers.

**PageEditRequest/userPickerWidget:**
[image: PageEditRequest/userPickerWidget]

**Function associates to the custom value of userPickerWidget:**
[image: Function associates to the custom value of userPickerWidget]

But I don't know how can I associate a new stage to an another approver...

I tried a lot of things that failed

Have you any ideas?

I want to have this type of results without any client interaction:

**Desired result:**
[image: Desired result]

Comment: When you are clicking on '+Add Stage' button. Add your predefined approvers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earlier answer points to solve the problem where user are adding stage manually. If you want all stages and all approvers list to be added automatically, follow the below steps.

1. Open Edit Request page, in that page you can find event `onAttach`, this event will trigger when page is being loaded and data has not loaded yet. DMS Template has already provided a method called `startLoading()` to this Event.
2. Locate `startLoading()` method in Client Script named `EditRequestPage_Request`. This method is calling `loadEditRequestPage()` method internally. Locate `loadEditRequestPage()` method.
3. This method is adding a default stage (i.e. Stage 1) to the approval workflow. We need to perform our operations here for Automatically add approvers.
4. Locate the line `requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem` in the code, this line is Adding a Stage to the workflow. So we need to add this line multiple times to Add multiple stages. In my below code I've show cased for 2 stages.

Code for adding 2 stages and 1 approver at each stage.

```
if (requestDs.item.WorkflowStages.length === 0) {

    requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {
    var createDatasource = requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.relations.Approvers.modes.create;
    var draft = createDatasource.item;
    draft.Email = 'darpan.sanghavi@abc.com';
    draft.Name = 'Darpan Sanghavi';          


    createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });

    });      

     requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {
    var createDatasource = requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.relations.Approvers.modes.create;
    var draft = createDatasource.item;
    draft.Email = 'darpan.sanghavi@xyz.com';
    draft.Name = 'Darn Alarm';          


    createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });
    app.closeDialog();

    }); 

}
```

5. In the above code I've added lines inside `requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem` call, this call is creating a stage, inside a stage I've added Predefined Approver by Creating New Approver Data source.

This code still can be changed for incorporating changes like User's Thumbnail and some other changes, but this will help you get going. Add/Change code as per need.

Comment: @busvlaneint : If you want to initiate this workflow from Google Drive itself, I've found a way and posted detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986952/initiate-appmaker-document-approval-from-google-drive)

Comment: Just found out that this method does add 2 stages and 1 approver at each stage however, it does not flow well as both stages will receive the approval email at the same time. That mean the 2nd approver can approve the request first before the 1st approver approve it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question :

> how can I associate a new stage to an another approver

Whenever you are clicking on `+ ADD STAGE` button, you can add your predefined approvers in method `createStage`. You can do so by adding Approver in `request.WorkflowStages`.
[image]

Try doing this. If it does not work let me know. I will try to provide you some more code.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand, i'm a beginner... You Say that i Can create an approver in method createStage with request.WorkflowStages but in request.WorkflowStages There IS no email etc.. Can you show me an example please?

Comment: Whhy do you need emails in request.WorkflowStages? This option will set your approver on pageLoad. Rest of the flow will be same

Comment: @busvlaneint : Please check below answer, it has exact code as per your need. It will auto populate two users on 2 different stages on Page load.

Answer (score 0):

The code from Darpan do add 2 stages and 1 approver at each stage *automatically*, however if you can see from the screenshot below, both Stage1 and Stage2 is under **Current** approval status. Which mean Stage2 approver can approve first before the Stage1 approver approve it yet. This is not correct is it?

[image]