# App Maker Document Approval Template : Add Default Approvers automatically

Tags: google-app-maker

Set standard approvers and maintain proper route operation in the Document Approval Template.

I am using the code developed by Darpan in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186512/app-maker-document-approval-template-how-can-i-add-default-approvers), but I am having problems in the routes for document approval.
Now I need to solve the same problem that [@alep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54086193/11750756) commented. Using the code, the 2 stages send an email at the same time to both approvers.  I need Approver 1 to receive it first and then send it to Approver 2 just as it is in the default Documentation Approval template.

Approver 1 must be current, not both approvers.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
if (requestDs.item.WorkflowStages.length === 0) {
    requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {
    var createDatasource = requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.relations.Approvers.modes.create;
    var draft = createDatasource.item;
    draft.Email = 'darpan.sanghavi@abc.com';
    draft.Name = 'Darpan Sanghavi';          


    createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });

    });      

     requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {
    var createDatasource = requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.relations.Approvers.modes.create;
    var draft = createDatasource.item;
    draft.Email = 'darpan.sanghavi@xyz.com';
    draft.Name = 'Darn Alarm';          


    createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });
    app.closeDialog();

    }); 

}
```

The code automatically add approvers and works ok, but the approval routes are sent at the same time as in the example below.

The idea is to include approver 1 automatically, where the user can not modify it. And approver 2 is manually added by the user.
example:

```
    if (requestDs.item.WorkflowStages.length === 0) {

          requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {
      var createDatasource = requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.relations.Approvers.modes.create;
    var draft = createDatasource.item;
    draft.Email = 'employee@abc.com.br';
    draft.Name = 'Employee';
    createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });

            });

requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {


     app.closeDialog();


  });
```

**Aprover 1 automatically + Approver 2 Manual  :**
[image]
**Both remain as current  :**
[image]

When we add the 2 approvers manually, the first is the current one and the second one is on hold.
I do not understand why it works manually but adding the approver automatically all are marked as current.

I think the solution is in the code below, but I have not done well yet.

RequestManagementPrivate
    /**
     * Update list of request's approvers marking those currently 
     * responsible for approval with Pending status.
     *
     * @param {Request} request - request to process.
     */

> ```
> function initializeNextStageAndApprovers_(request) {
>   var allStages = request.WorkflowStages;
>   sortByOrderNo_(allStages);
>
>   var updateApproverStatus = function(a) {
>     a.Status = Status.Pending;
>   };
>
>   var currentLevel = -1;
>   for (var i = 0; i < allStages.length; i++) {
>     var stage = allStages[i];
>     if (stage.Status === Status.Draft || stage.Status === Status.Pending) {
>       if (currentLevel === -1) {
>         currentLevel = stage.OrderNo;
>       }
>
>       if (currentLevel === stage.OrderNo && stage.Status === Status.Draft) {
>         stage.Status = Status.Pending;
>         stage.Approvers.forEach(updateApproverStatus);
>
>         app.saveRecords([stage].concat(stage.Approvers));
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: You need to tweak the code given a little bit for achieving your goal. Please provide us what all you have tried in addition to what was already given.

Comment: Thanks Darpan, I updated with some info of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The solution to the problem with stages is here, tanks user11893732: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404280/app-maker-document-approval-template-add-default-approvers-and-notify-owner-th