# App Maker Document approval template : Add Default Approvers and notify Owner the status automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am studying the document approval template, and added default Approvers successfully by using the code below.

[App Maker Document approval template : How can I Add Default Approvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186512/app-maker-document-approval-template-how-can-i-add-default-approvers/51188680?noredirect=1#comment89363757_51188680)

My question is that after adding these code in app maker, function notifyApproversAboutRequest_(request) still work, but the function notifyOwnerAboutRequestRejected(request) and function notifyOwnerAboutRequestApproved_(request) do not work anymore. Can anyone tell me how to resolve the problem?  Thank you!

```
if (requestDs.item.WorkflowStages.length === 0) {
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.Status = window.Status.Draft;
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.Type = "All";

var createDatasource = 
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.relations.Approvers.modes.create;
var draft = createDatasource.item;
draft.Email = 'darpan.sanghavi@abc.com';
draft.Name = 'Darpan Sanghavi';          
createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });

});    
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.OrderNo = 
getNextOrderNumberForApprover(requestDs.item);
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.Status = window.Status.Draft;
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.Type = "All";

var createDatasource = 
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.relations.Approvers.modes.create;
var draft = createDatasource.item;
draft.Email = 'darpan.sanghavi@xyz.com';
draft.Name = 'Darn Alarm';          

createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });
app.closeDialog();

}); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve with these changes.
Both notifyOwnerAboutRequestRejected(request) and function notifyOwnerAboutRequestApproved_(request) are ok:

```
          if (requestDs.item.WorkflowStages.length === 0) {
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.Status = window.Status.Draft;
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.Type = "All";

var createDatasource = 
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.relations.Approvers.modes.create;
var draft = createDatasource.item;
draft.Email = 'Test@test.com.br';
draft.Name = 'Test';          
createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });

});    
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.createItem(function() {
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.OrderNo = 
getNextOrderNumberForApprover(requestDs.item);
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.Status = window.Status.Draft;
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.item.Type = "All";

var createDatasource = 
requestDs.relations.WorkflowStages.relations.Approvers.modes.create;
var draft = createDatasource.item;
draft.Email = 'test2@test.com.br';
draft.Name = 'Test2';          

createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });
  app.closeDialog();
    }); 


      } else {
        app.closeDialog();
      }
    }, 
    failure: function() {
      app.closeDialog();
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks so much for your code, it solved my problem with stages.