# Understanding the Document Approval template by Google AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

Almost a month I tried to understand the template but found a dead end. Had tried posted [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/appmaker-users/pWXYuYHmJFI/XTdyFr71BQAJ) on the App Maker Users Forum to request on a tutorial video to explain on how's the template work .. yet still no reply from them.

Can anyone with the Google AppMaker expertise kindly explain to me how's this different layer of approval been done. In this example from [Document Approval](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/document-approval/) template, user need to manually key in their approver. But what I try to achieve is that, the system will automatically set the different layer of approval when user submit the request. Can anyone guide me on how to do that .. any help from the floor? Thanks ..

[image: screenshot of the approval stages interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've been working on this template since last 5 months and you will need to do a lot of customization to use it in PROD like environment and I think that is okay because Google team has provided us a starting point by providing us templates. We need to customize it as per our need.

Here are the steps that template will do for you.

1. End user will see all the request he has already made on the home screen. If any. On the right hand side '+' button, user can start a new request.
2. Here an end user can choose any document from Google Drive/ Team Drive and provide the description for that file and click on 'ADD' button. On the next screen he can provide a list of approvers. Here this template supports both sequential and parallel approvals. i.e. More than one approver can take action at same time or you can have a workflow like approvals where Approver 1 approves first then only Approver 2 gets notified for the action.
3. Once all approvers are in place users can submit the request and Doc is sent for Approvals with the approvers.
4. Approvers can Approve/Reject the request with Comments. After all approvals are done workflow is closed.

Now your second question is somewhat unclear. I think you are referring to Auto Approver names should be added. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186512/app-maker-document-approval-template-how-can-i-add-default-approvers/51188680?noredirect=1#comment89363757_51188680) if your question is same, or else please provide exact use case.

Comment: Wow great tips Darpan!! yes the second question is almost the same such those post. I want to add a predefined approver from stage 1 to stage 3 without client interaction. But I don't understand how can I achieve that by using the CreateStage() method mentioned? can you please explain it step by step if you don't mind .. really appreciate it

Comment: @MuhammadAlifBinAzali- : Sure I am working on it. I will post the updated code in some time for your second question.

Comment: @MuhammadAlifBinAzali- :: Please check the above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51493731/1423927) once again. I've added basis code for achieving your customization. Change code as per need basis. Incorporate your custom logic instead of Hard code names there.

Comment: wow Darpan you are really cool thank you so much it works!!! got few question to ask but I guess need to post them separately .. anyway great help thanks!

Comment: @MuhammadAlifBinAzali-: Glad to hear that it worked for you.!! Please mark the answer as Accepted/Up vote if it has resolved your query.

Comment: @MuhammadAlifBinAzali-: If you want to initiate this workflow from Google Drive itself, I've found a way and posted detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986952/initiate-appmaker-document-approval-from-google-drive)